# Using tiles as texture when zooming in on Object in Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, zooming, tile

I have a problem with an smartphone (android so far) app I am programming in unity3d. 
I got the following set up:
I have a sphere on which, so far, I have a texture of the world. It's resolution is already set to the maximum but when I "zoom in" on it it just looks disgusting. I'd like to reload texture tiles like in Google maps to have a higher resolution without having a too big impact on the memory. Is that approach a good one at all? And if so: how do I do that? 
Haven't found the right things so far or I just got them wrong.

EDIT: As some people probably get me wrong I try it again with some more details.
What I am trying to set up is the Earth as a sphere with a map. That map is okay as long as you dont zoom in too far, which is obvious because of the textures finit resolution. Now, to still have good graphic quality, when being zoomed in that far that one could see streets in a city I want to load additional "satelite pictures" like Google Maps does it (you know: you zoom in and Google Maps always reloads the images in that specific area to still provide a good graphic  quality). How do I achieve that specific behaviour? Providing all the tiles i need is no problem, I got a Vector Graphic from which I could export all the needed tiles, but i don't know how to reload those tiles when zooming in at that specific area (to reduce memory consumption, drawcalls, etc).

Any help is really appreciated as I am a beginner in programming with unity. Thank you very much in advance!

Dustin

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually zooming in or moving the camera physically closer? Unity has some internal filters that make textures easier to load at a longer distance. When zooming, the camera isnt actually moving closer meaning the more detailed version of it will not load correctly.

Also check your Max Texture Size setting for the texture you are using. Maybe it is turned down too low. Try turning it up to a higher resolution.

If it still looks blurry up close with Max Texture Size turned higher, your texture may not be high enough resolution to begin with. Make it a high enough resolution that it looks good up close. Then begin lowering the Max Texture Size resolution until up close it is "good enough".

Next, typically, it will start looking blurry in the distance or have distinct linear transitions from looking good to blurry. You can fix this by turning up the Ansio Level. **Use this with caution** because it increases the rendering load. Only use what you need, especially for mobile games.

Comment: At first: thank you very much you for your reply.
I didnt know, i have to move the camera itself to get a better graphic rendered by unity. Though this does not solve my problem either...

I edit my initial post to be more precise.